# I Need to Know the Benefits of Separating SSN parts into Three Separate Tables

Tags: cryptography

I have been using three separate tables for social security numbers: lgls1, lgls2, and lgls3.  Each table stores one of the three parts of social security numbers.  Is this more secure than one field, in the same table as the first, middle, and last names?  I'm a novice, and do not understand IT verbage, so I need easy-to-understand terms.

Each table has a primary key, which corresponds to the "names table" ID field.

So, instead of:
personID
personLast
personFirst
personMiddle
personSSN

I have:
personID
personLast
personFirst
personMiddle

lgls1ID
lgls1_

lgls2ID
lgls2_

lgls3ID
lgls3_

Comment: Douglas - is this a security question?

Answer (score 10):

The only security benefit is that you've got better job security because no one else is going to enjoy working with such architecture.

There's no real security benefit to splitting the SSN up into three tables.

Answer (score 1):

All this provides is "security by obscurity".  Someone looking through your database *may* not realize that you're storing a Social Security number, but that's only because the column name appears to be gibberish.  Anyone who actually looks at your data will say "Here are three numbers, here are two more, here are four more. This must be a Social Security number!"  Not very secure.

You can make it more "secure" by obfuscating it further: changing the order of the parts (put two digits in 1, three in 2...), combining them in various ways (six digits in one table, three in another), adding 5 to each digit (mod 10) or otherwise transforming it in some way that you can undo. However, once you start doing that, you may as well do it correctly and encrypt the data.

Security by obscurity is only as good as your ability to think of ways to secure it. You have to assume that anyone able to get in to your database is going to be cleverer than you and will be able to unobscure anything you obscured.  Encryption is the only safe bet.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very odd scheme.  I've worked with a lot of personal data for 20+ years and never seen it done this way.

The only reason I can think of for doing this sort of this is support for partial-SSN access.  Consider a common use case, a user verifying his or her own identify by entering the last four of the SSN.  To support this use case, you would need to provide your application with a DB user with access permissions to lgls3, but could explicitly deny access to lgls1 and lgls2.  That way, if the credentials are ever compromised, the hacker would unable to retrieve the full social security number.  On the other hand, there are other, better ways to handle this use case (e.g. by taking a one-way hash of the last four and storing it in a different column, then using a View to enforce column-level security).

Another possible reason, shot in the dark here.... if lgls1, lgls2, and lgls3 are on different data partitions, they may end up in different backups, which may help protect you if anyone ever broke into your off-site backup storage and stole a couple of tapes.  Assuming you took the trouble to send your backups to different sites.

Other than that, I can't see much benefit other than security by obscurity.